# AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager Oracle Connector failed

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have setup the connection manager from SSIS to Oracle as:

[image]

In the Oracle source:

[image]

I can preview the data successfully:
[image]

However, upon attempting to execute the packge, the erorr appears as:

```
SSIS package "C:\Users\kakah\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestExcel\TestExcel\INV_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x802092A7 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [17]: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "DESCRIPTION" with a length of 600 to database column "DESCRIPTION" with a length of 150.
Warning: 0x802092A7 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [17]: Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "LONG_DESCRIPTION" with a length of 2000 to database column "LONG_DESCRIPTION" with a length of 150.
Error: 0x2C0 at INV_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL: OCI error encountered. ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
Error: 0x20F at Data Flow Task, Oracle Source [62]: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager Oracle Connector failed with error code 0x80004005.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Oracle Source failed validation and returned error code 0x80004005.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "C:\Users\kakah\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestExcel\TestExcel\INV_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

What could I be missing? How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the project and go to properties --> Configuration Properties --> Debugging, did you make sure Run64BitRuntime is False?  Sometimes that gets toggles to True and will break it.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by executing the package? Execute it from BIDS/SSDT or SQL Server agent?

Are there any configuration files/dynamic configurations that you are using? From what it appears, the tnsnames.ora file that your connection manager is using at run time has bad connection information.

Comment: It ended up that that connection manager was not detailed enough. Using simply "SERVICE_NAME" was fine for the metadata preview, but did not work for execution. I had to specify: "HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME". This was very difficult to track down since the data preview was working, I was not looking at the connections anymore...

Answer (score 0):

SSDT 2017 connecting to Oracle 9i.

Issue : on my windows 10 laptop I had installed 10G 32 Bit and 11G 64 bit client installed

Resolution : Remove all the clients and install only one version of Client 11G both 32 and 64 bit client and SSIS worked like a charm